# Exporting nodes except for specific fields

Tags: nodes, migrations, importing-exporting, backups

I'm wanting to transfer a set of content from one drupal site to another - the field structure etc is the same but there are a couple of requirements:

1) I need to be able export only nodes of a specific content type.
2) I need to be able to exclude certain fields from being exported.

I've had a look at a few modules - Node Export, Backup and Migrate - but these don't appear to handle the exclusion of certain custom fields.

Could anyone point me in the right direction of a module that can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use feeds -> https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds for custom export / import of nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds  Use feed module for import/export node and user.